# SQL Server SELECT rows that begin with Parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains a column named NUMBERS which has the values 1234, 1235, 1278, 4567, 5434, and 7890. I am trying to write a procedure that will SELECT all values that begin with a number @NUMBER.
I was thinking it would look something like this:

```
 DECLARE @NUMBER as int 
 SET @NUMBER = 1
 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE [NUMBER] LIKE (@NUMBER + '%')
```

But that is giving me an error 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int'.

How can I make it so that if I enter 1 as my @NUMBER it will return everything that begins with 1 (i.e. 1234, 1235, 1278)

Comment: You need to convert @NUMBER to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert numbers to strings so the `+` operator is understood to be string concatenation (rather than addition):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE cast([NUMBER] as varchar(255)) LIKE cast(@NUMBER as varchar(255)) + '%';
```

Because `like` does an implicit `cast()` anyways, you should be explicit about what the query is doing.  I add a cast to the first part as well.

Note:  You could also fix this by changing the declaration of the variable:

```
 DECLARE @NUMBER as varchar(255);
 SET @NUMBER = '1';

 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE [NUMBER] LIKE (@NUMBER + '%');
```